# XCode Error when deploying to real device: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am getting the following error when trying to deploy to a real IOS device with my Macbook Pro M2:

[image]

I cannot find any "select your Developer App certificate" option in the VPN & Device Management screen:
[image]

Here is the message from the error:

Verify that the Developer App certificate for your account is trusted on your device. Open Settings on the device and navigate to General -> VPN & Device Management, then select your Developer App certificate to trust it.

Here is the full stack trace below:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)
Domain: IDELaunchCoreDevice
Code: 0
Recovery Suggestion: Verify that the Developer App certificate for your account is trusted on your device. Open Settings on the device and navigate to General -> VPN & Device Management, then select your Developer App certificate to trust it.
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-12-23 10:42:00 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDELaunchCoreDeviceWorker;
}
--
The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)
Domain: NSOSStatusErrorDomain
Code: -10814
User Info: {
    "_LSFunction" = runEvaluator;
    "_LSLine" = 1608;
}
--

Event Metadata: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_isCoreDevice" = 1;
    "device_model" = "iPhone12,3";
    "device_osBuild" = "17.1.2 (21B101)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "dvt_coredevice_version" = "355.7.6";
    "dvt_mobiledevice_version" = "1643.60.2";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 84635;
    "operation_errorCode" = 0;
    "operation_errorDomain" = IDELaunchCoreDevice;
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDELaunchCoreDeviceWorker;
    "operation_name" = IDERunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 3;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 99;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 8192;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_structuredConsoleMode" = 1;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphoneos17.2";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "17.2";
    "sdk_variant" = iphoneos;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 14.2.1 (Build 23C71)
Xcode 15.1 (22502) (Build 15C65)
Timestamp: 2023-12-23T11:42:00+01:00
```

This error does not occur when I deploy to a simulator locally. However it does occur when I deploy to any kind of IOS device (my iPhone, my iPad).

It is weird since it had just worked 2 days ago. I only changed very little in my codebase since then and I also checked out some old commits where it had worked previously and there it is now NOT working anymore.

- I am using ionic capacitor
- I am using XCode version: Version 15.1
- I am using Macos version: 14.2.1 (23C71)
- I am using IOS Version: 17.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was messing with the XCode deployment bundle indentifier. I tried to get the same app installed onto my device twice, once with a release bundle & once with a debug bundle, which both had a different bundle identifier. The release bundle had the original identifier `com.example.appname` and the debug bundle had the `com.example.appname.debug` .debug suffix. This messed some things up, I am not entirely sure how.

When I changed them to have the same bundle ID again, the error vanished.

Comment: I do the same thing because I use my app so I want to keep the debug build separate from the release one. I want to keep my real data in the release one while I’m often messing with the data (for example resetting it) in the debug one. Have you found an alternative solution, Felix?

Answer (score 0):

Try

Settings > Developer > Clear Trusted Computers

And make sure you have developer mode turned on.

Settings > Privacy & Security > Developer Mode > Toggle on Developer Mode.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention this but had I already tried this and it did not help.